# Why do the maximal the ideals of $\mathbb C[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ that contain $I$ correspond to the maximal ideals of $\mathbb C[x_1,\dots, x_n]/I$?

Tags: abstract-algebra

> Why do the maximal the ideals of $\mathbb C[x_1,\dots,x_n]$ that contain $I$ correspond to the maximal ideals of $\mathbb C[x_1,\dots, x_n]/I$?

In Artin, theorem 11.9.1, Artin says this result is by the correspondence theorem. How does this follow?

The correspondence theorem says the ideals of a ring $R$ correspond to the ideals of $R/I$. It doesn't say anything about maximal ideals.

Answer (score 0):

Let $M$ be maximal in $R$ and assume the ideal $M/I$ in $R/I$ is contained in another ideal, then by correspondence theorem, $M/I\subseteq S/I$ for some ideal $S$ in $R$ such that $M\subseteq S$. The maximality of $M$ in $R$ shows that $S=R$, so $S/I=R/I$, this proves the maximality of $M/I$ in $R/I$.

Comment: How does the correspondence theorem show $M/I \subset S/I$ implies $M\subset S$?

Comment: For what I know, the correspondence just says there is a bijection between the the ideals of $R/I$ and the ideals of $R$ containing $I$. It doesn't say anything about containment between the ideals in the ring.

Comment: You can look at this [link](https://www.maths.nottingham.ac.uk/personal/ibf/als3/leno.pdf).